# setup relationship one-to-one in Flask + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up a relationship between two tables which allows me to reach obj1.obj2.name where obj1 is one table, and obj2 is another table. Relationship is one-to-one (one person to one geographical region)

```
# Table one (Person)
class Person(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(100))
  region = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('region.id'))

# Table two (Region)
class Region(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

If I use Person.region (*where Person is an object of Person class*) I get the int of the primary key of the region of the user, but I would like to get the 'name' field associated with it.

I've figured out that this would work:

```
region = models.Region.query.filter_by(id=REGION_ID).first().name
```

but it's not applicable in my case since I need to access the 'name' field from a Flask template.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using `Person.region` in a query on `Person` or is this a particular person that you are accessing?  That is, `db.session.query(Person.region, etc...)` or `person = Person.get_or_404(1); person.region`?

Comment: sorry I should have been more clearer. I'm trying to work directly with and object derived from the Person class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I basically use your model, but:
1) changed the name of the FK column
1) added a `relationship` (please read [Relationship Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html) part of the documentation)

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    # @note: renamed the column, so that can use the name 'region' for
    # relationship
    region_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('region.id'))

    # define relationship
    region = db.relationship('Region', backref='people')


class Region(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

With this you are able to get the name of the region as below:

```
region_name = my_person.region.name  # navigate a 'relationship' and get its 'name' attribute
```

In order to make sure that the region is loaded from the database at the same time as the person is, you can use `joinedload` option:

```
p = (db.session.query(Person)
     .options(db.eagerload(Person.region))
     .get(1)
     )

print(p)
# below will not trigger any more SQL, because `p.region` is already loaded
print(p.region.name)
```